# c# Web page Radio Button Checked Auto

Tags: c#, radio-button

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     web.Document.GetElementById("youtubeURL").SetAttribute("value", textUrl.Text);
     web.Document.GetElementById("ftype").InvokeMember("checked");
     web.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
}
web.Document.GetElementById("ftype").InvokeMember("checked");
```

I need to make the radio button "checked". How can I do this?   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if its simply checking the radiobutton, I would suggest 
radioButton1.Checked = true;

Comment: Web page automatic Checked 
program no Radio Button